# Vue.js / Algolia - Debugging

Tags: vue.js, algolia, laravel-4.2

Looking for help debugging some code i've been staring at for 3 days. It's Vue.js / Laravel / Algolia. I feel that there's an error somewhere in my model but I can't see to get the it to fire. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.:

```
<input type="text" v-model="name" v-on:keyup="search" debounce="500">
<div id="results">
    <article v-for="user in users">
        <h2>@{{ user.name }}</h2>
    </article>
</div>
```

and:

```
new Vue({

        el: '#results',

        data: {

                query: '',
                users: [] 

    },

        ready: function()  {

              this.client = algoliasearch('myKey', 'myKey');
              this.index = this.client.initIndex('getstarted_actors');



        },


        methods: {

            search: function() {

                this.index.search(this.query, function(error, results) {

                    this.users = results.hits;

         }.bind(this));

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: What's not working? What does it do? What errors show up in your browser's console?

Comment: @ceejayoz every since I added the submit box theres no JSON response in console log. Doesnt fire at all..

Comment: Where's the console.log? Can't find it.

Comment: Maybe try a very simple jsfiddle that we can play with, thanks

Comment: Can you try with an empty `options` object after `this.query,` ? The prototype for the search method is `search(query, options, callback)`.

Comment: @Jerska in fact the search signature accepts a lot of cases:

- ()
- (query)
- (query, params)

....

Comment: @vvo But does it accept `(query, callback)` without `options` ?

Comment: Yep it works without options also

Comment: Ok, I owe an apology to everyone that's comment so far. Thanks for showing love by contributing. @vvo thanks but there's no console.log cause I wasn't getting a response. Also, i'm going to add a JSfiddle shortly. jerska I'm not familiar enough with javascript to make the edits you refer to unless you send me to documentation. ricardo wow bro I got a response with your change so thanks alot! Only, when I make the change to data: adding users: [] it echos {{ user.name }} so i'm not going to do that part. Having the input outside the div was the major problem. I need to work accuracy however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the error you're getting, but:
Your v-model is outside the scope of your vue instance.
Try to put it inside the #results div:

```
<div id="results">
    <input type="text" v-model="name" v-on:keyup="search" debounce="500" />
    <article v-for="user in users">
        <h2>@{{ user.name }}</h2>
    </article>
</div>
```

edit the data in your vue instance

```
data: {

        query: '',
        users: [],
        name: ''

}
```

Comment: I didn't have to add: "users: []," but the scope issue was the problem. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A small tip for future. In order to debug in Vue.js I suggest you to use the chrome extension.

It'll allow to see warnings, errors and also inspect your components.

It will work only with non minified versions of Vue.js.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools